# SNMP traps not caught in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, snmp

I have an SNMP client, sending my PC SNMP traps with destination port 162.
I run a  sniffer (Wireshark) from my PC, and see that the traps are indeed received.
The SNMP.exe and SNMPTRAP.exe system processes are up and running (I've even restarted them),and SNMPTRAP.exe is listening to port 162. I have no activated firewall (whether Windows or 3rd party).

The problem: On my PC I have three different applications, all registered to SNMPTRAP.exe. These are all off-the-shelf sw, not something I wrote. MG-SOFT Trap Ringer is, f.e., one of
them. NONE OF THEM CATCHES ANY OF THE TRAPS, and I have no idea where exactly the failure is.

Do you have any idea what may be causing this? Or how, perhaps, I can debug the SNMPTRAP.exe process?

Thanks!

Comment: [Question on ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/406304/unreceived-snmp-traps)

I have an almost identical question on ServerFault, where I have described it in more detail. In short the resolutions listed below have not solved my issue.

I have my NMS configured to be listening on the correct port, confirmed with Wireshark that the SMNP packets have been sent, and with a combination of netstat and tasklist that the NMS is holding the PID associated with the port. 

Any further ideas?#

Answer (score 0):

How you can eliminate and corner the problem is, try below stuff.

1. How are sure its not catching traps ( since u see them in wireshark). I mean, should they be displayed on some GUI Screen, if yes are the fields empty? or logged into some file, if yes are you sure you are checking the correct file, have you configured either through conf files or command line options which file the traps need to be logged in?
2. If step 1 does not work, try installing or configuring the whole setup on different pc /laptop and see if it works?
3. If step 2 does not work, try a different trap daemon program ( SNMPTRAP.EXE), plenty of open source programs exist, if you could capture with different daemon program, then some issue with SNMPTRAP.EXE you are using.

I'm sure one of these steps should work for you, if not get back :)

Comment: Thanks!
1. Trap Ringer is a GUI presenting the received traps. As I said it's off-the-shelf. 2. On a different PC with all the default configuration everything works just fine. On another one, however, it has the exact same problem, and we can't find the common denominator. 3.If a different program will capture it won't do me any good. The people using what I'm working on can't use (and why should they? It's supposed to work) something other than SNMPTRAP.exe

Comment: the third option is just to isolate the problem , if it was with the SNMPTRAP.EXE itself ..

Answer (score 0):

You may disable Microsoft Trap Service in Services panel. Then MG-SOFT TRAP Ringer will work.

The reason is simply that when Microsoft's SnmpTrap.exe monitors port 162, it prevents other applications, such as MG-SOFT's one from monitoring that port.

Comment: Tried that. Still doesn't work. It appears that something is wrong with my port 162, since when I sent the trap to 166 everything is fine. I don't have a firewall or anything blocking the port (that I know of)

Comment: What is returned if you run this "netstat -aon" at command prompt? Find the PID for port 162 and then execute "tasklist" to find the process name. The hardest part is to get rid of that process, and it is highly dependent on the process itself.